# How do I use the Google Calendar API client library for Ruby to get a list of calendar IDs for only my account?

Tags: ruby, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a web application that takes data from my google calendar account and puts it on a website that uses its own calendar program. I don't want to have to get user permission for the account every time I run the program, since I am the user of the account, and according to *https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/auth/service-accounts* and *https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2*, it seems the only way to do this is to use a service account. Is this the ideal option for my scenario? At any rate, I set up a service account, generated the JSON file with my credentials, and attempted to create the code that would return a list of my calendar IDs so I can access all of my calendars:

```
require 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
require 'googleauth'
require 'oauth'

cert_path = Gem.loaded_specs['google-api-client'].full_gem_path+'/lib/cacerts.pem'
ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = cert_path

ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'C:\Users\eric\Desktop\Tripleseat Project\My Project-6006a5b60113.json'

def createServiceObject()
    service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
    scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
    service.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scope)
    service.authorization.fetch_access_token!
    return service
end

service = createServiceObject()
response = service.list_calendar_lists()
puts response
puts response.items
```

This code does not run into any errors when I run it from the command prompt, and I do get a response from the API. However, the response.items field always turns out empty even though my google calendar account clearly lists multiple calendars under the "My Calendars" menu on the left side of the screen, and each calendar has multiple events associated with it. I'm guessing the problem is that my service account is not properly associated with my google calendar account. However, I cannot find any documentation that explains how to associate a service account with a single google account. There is a bunch of information about how using a Google Apps Domain, Google App Engine, or Google Compute Engine can let you access the accounts of multiple users, but I don't want to use any of these things for my relatively simple Ruby program (I'm not even using Rails or Sinatra). I would rather just host the program on a Heroku server, where I already have other similar programs set up. Are there any other reasons why the API response would turn up empty? Should the API even be returning anything at all if it doesn't know which account to get data from?

Comment: I see you are storing your app credentials in environment variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" but you haven't used it anywhere in the authorization phase while requesting for access token, why so?

Comment: From what I understand, if you're using Service Accounts, its getting Calendar items from that account, not yours. Remember, Service Accounts are server-to-server interaction in which the account belongs to the application instead of the user.

Comment: @sghosh968: get_application_default is a method that is part of Google Application Default Credentials, and the documentation for that says that "The environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is checked. If this variable is specified it should point to a file that defines the credentials.

Comment: @adjuremods: Then how do I access the google calendar of a service account?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem was. I needed to go to my google calendars account and change the settings of the calendar so that it could give permission to share its information with my service account.  I had to click the gear icon in the upper right corner of the google calendar page, go to settings, go to calendars, click Shared:Edit Settings, enter the e-mail address for my service account, and set the permission settings to one of the make changes options on a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to use the service account.  You should be able to use oauth2 to have a user authorize your service to read and manage their calendars then save the access token and refresh token.

Comment: The problem with this is that I am the user who needs to authorize the calendar. Its annoying and impractical to have to click yes on a webpage every time I want to run my program. I may want to run it several times in a row for testing.

Comment: You want to request offline access when you authorize.  You can save the tokens and when the access token expires, get a new one with the refresh token - there is no need for you to authorize each time.